# Need help identifying the syntax error on line 20

Tags: mysql, sql

[db Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=53f82d036e4b683022dfe412ef99c2ae)

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (select post_id from (
>         SELECT pm.post' at line 20

```
-- Deleting all duplicate products in wp_posts table

DELETE FROM
wp_posts WHERE ID IN ( SELECT ID FROM
(
select ID,post_title,post_type,meta_value from 
(SELECT wp_postmeta.ID,post_title,post_type ,meta_value,
row_number()over(partition by post_title order by wp_postmeta.meta_value) rn                           
FROM   wp_postmeta 
JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
  AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 

) t where t.rn <> 1
) AS aliasx
)

-- Deleting all corresponding wp_postmeta.post_ids that don't have a match in wp_posts.id after the duplicate deletion above

DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (select post_id from (
  SELECT pm.post_id 
  FROM
    wp_postmeta pm
    LEFT JOIN 
    wp_posts p
    ON p.id = pm.post_id
  WHERE
    p.id IS NULL

) AS aliasy )
```

In MYPHPAdmin I get this:

> `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(partition by post_title order by wp_postmeta.meta_value) rn '
>   at line 5`

In online validator https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/
I get this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: '(
>   partition by post_title order by ' at line 21

Seems to be a whole bunch of different errors depending on where I run the query.

Comment: If you add semicolons at the end of each delete statement, your code will work: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vN7d8jGzfZDqryXjPJMzCa/1

Comment: I'm also getting `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by post_title order by wp_postmeta.meta_value) rn ' at line 5` now.  What does it mean?

Comment: Is there more to this query?  Because your second error statement references a create table statement, but I don't see that anywhere in what you've given us.  Makes me suspicious you forgot a parenthesis or semi-colon somewhere.

Comment: In the real database, there won't be a create table statement as the tables are already created.  So probably focus on the other errors...

Comment: I think your DB version doesn't support `row_number()` analytic function.

Comment: What is your MySQL version? You need at least 8.0 to use window functions

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Server version: 5.7.25 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Even using 10.1.37-MariaDB I'm still getting `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by post_title order by wp_postmeta.meta_value) rn                    ' at line 8`  Doesn't MariaDB support windows functions?